# 404 response on docker nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I am making a small TS application but got stuck while setting up reverse proxy.
I have been trying to fix this for a few days, here's by current setup:
Docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    build:
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx

  translation_web:
    image: httpd
    build:
      dockerfile: ./translate/Dockerfile
    container_name: translation_web
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
```

nginx .conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location /preklad {
            proxy_pass http://translation_web:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }
```

Here's what I think I am doing:
I am forwarding to port 80 (within composer created network) of translation_web HTTPD container.

When I access HTTPD container on port 8080 (port that has been mapped to host machine) through browser, it returns a website (expected behaviour)

When I access HTTPD container on port 80 from nginx container through cURL, HTTPD returns a website (again, expected)

But when I use proxy_pass in nginx container, and go to localhost, I see 404 response from HTTPD (not nginx).

This seems very odd to me because the 404 response from HTTPD indicates that there is a successful forward, however the path to resources somehow changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same issue.

Well, as [this serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass) and [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/17r8dv3/cant_get_proxy_pass_to_work_keep_getting_404_not/) point out... *And as always in this kind of situation*, we were missing a `/`

Here is how your nginx.conf should look like :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /preklad {
        proxy_pass http://translation_web:80/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

At least, from the research and experimentation I did, this worked for me, but I'm still no expert on reverse-proxies and particularly Nginx. Still, hope I could help someone with the same issue as ours.